# One SSL certificate on One IP Address Served for Multiple Domains

Tags: apache, ssl, server, virtualhost

I have a server with one IP address assigned to it. I would like to use one Wildcard SSL certificate for multiple sub-domains. Is that achievable using Apache?

Is it possible to have multiple Apache Virtual Host files which use the same Wildcard SSL certificate with the same IP address used for different subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could as long as you have a wildcard certificate there wont be any issue.

You can create virtual hosts and add the same certificate and key, to all the hosts that you want to have SSL.

Please refer to the wiki from apache.org below while configuring
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts